# Is it possible to dynamically import web components into an Ionic 5 app, running on Angular 8?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dynamic, import, web-component

I am having an Ionic 5 hybrid app (with Angular 8 doing the heavy lifting) and I would like to dynamically import web components that I have previously generated with @angular/elements.

The idea is to use the variant of import that works like a function, as documented on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), like so:

```
import('/modules/my-module.js').then(module => {...})
```

I have created the web components and they work fine if I import them statically, like this:

```
import '../webcomponents/item.js';
```

However, dynamically, all bets are off. At first I thought, webpack was destroying the paths, but nothing as complicated as that. Look at what works:

```
import('../webcomponents/item.js').then(mm => {...})
```

works like a charm.

But

```
const path = '../webcomponents/item.js';
import(path).then(mm => {...})
```

gets the following reaction: `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../webcomponents/item.js'`, and a little further below

```
Warnings while compiling
...
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Any ideas what could work here? The difference is just between using the path directly as a string inside of import(), or putting it into a variable first. What kind of voodoo is that? Is webpack still interfering? I have reduced the entire app to this code, so there is not much else that could be tripping here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import('../webcomponents/item.js').then(mm => {}); // works

const path = '../webcomponents/item.js';
import(path).then(mm => {}); // doesn't

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: ``,
    styles: [],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```